# Is there a way to check whether a type is iterable within Julia's type system?

Tags: julia

Collections in Julia need to support three functions to be iterable: start, next, and done.

Is there currently a way to express that an input x to a function needs to be iterable within the type system? If not, is this on the roadmap?

Answer (score 11):

Is it possible? Yes, but not in a very elegant way:

```
julia> x = 1:5
1:5

julia> applicable(start, x)
true

julia> applicable(next,x,start(x))
true

julia> applicable(done,x,start(x))
true
```

I'm not sure how to get around the need for the `start(x)`s - maybe checking for `start` will be "good enough".

As for a more sensible way, this would need multiple inheritance or interfaces, which is under discussion, e.g. [here is one issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6975), it links to others.

Comment: without defining an object of said type, we can check for the definition of start on the type. For example to check `Symbol` (non-iterable) we see `length(methods(start,(Symbol,)))` is zero.

Comment: If you have types and not objects, you can also use `method_exists`